# Why when trying to move the mouse around 360c degrees the mouse cursor is stuttering in the middle?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

The mouse is not moving the mouse pointer/cursor is stuck in the middle and stuttering/dancing/shaking.

This is the code I'm using for the mouse input:

```
    private void ProcessInputCamera(float amount)
    {
        previousState = currentState;
        currentState = Mouse.GetState();
        MouseState currentMouseState = Mouse.GetState();
        if (currentMouseState != originalMouseState)
        {
            float xDifference = currentMouseState.X - originalMouseState.X;
            float yDifference = currentMouseState.Y - originalMouseState.Y;
            leftrightRot -= rotationSpeed * xDifference * amount;
            updownRot -= rotationSpeed * yDifference * amount;
            Mouse.SetPosition(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2);
        }

        Vector3 moveVector = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) || keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            moveVector += new Vector3(0, 0, -1);
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down) || keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
            moveVector += new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) || keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
            moveVector += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) || keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            moveVector += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Q))
            moveVector += new Vector3(0, 100, 0);
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Z))
            moveVector += new Vector3(0, -100, 0);
        AddToCameraPosition(moveVector * amount);
    }

    private void AddToCameraPosition(Vector3 vectorToAdd)
    {
        Matrix cameraRotation = Matrix.CreateRotationX(updownRot) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(leftrightRot);
        Vector3 rotatedVector = Vector3.Transform(vectorToAdd, cameraRotation);
        cameraPosition += moveSpeed * rotatedVector;
        UpdateViewMatrix(viewMatrix);
    }

    private void UpdateViewMatrix(Matrix viewMatrix)
    {
        Matrix cameraRotation = Matrix.CreateRotationX(updownRot) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(leftrightRot);

        Vector3 cameraOriginalTarget = new Vector3(0, 0, -1);
        Vector3 cameraRotatedTarget = Vector3.Transform(cameraOriginalTarget, cameraRotation);
        Vector3 cameraFinalTarget = cameraPosition + cameraRotatedTarget;

        Vector3 cameraOriginalUpVector = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
        Vector3 cameraRotatedUpVector = Vector3.Transform(cameraOriginalUpVector, cameraRotation);

        viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, cameraFinalTarget, cameraRotatedUpVector);
    }
```

The keys are working they are rotating the terrain.
But with the mouse i want to be able to change my point of view 360c degrees like first person view look around not to rotate the terrain and not to rotate the object but to let me look around 360c.

The problem is that this line:

```
Mouse.SetPosition(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2);
```

For some reason make the mouse cursour stuck in the middle and dance/shake/stutter.
If I uncomment this line not using it then the mouse is moving smooth but it dosent move anything 360c degrees i just can move the mouse cursor regular.

The question is why i cant move the mouse 360c like in first person shooter games ?

This is mt Game1.cs code including the camera code i marked it.
    http://pastebin.com/SF3iiftq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Mouse.SetPosition(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2);
```

This line sets the mouse cursor position to the center of the screen. Width / 2 and Height / 2 are the coordinates for the center of the screen. This line is executed once every game loop, so it keeps setting the cursor position back to the center. That's why the mouse gets stuck in the center and shakes when you try to move it.

Comment: Ok so i removed this line and im updating it with this line only once in the LoadContent method. Now why when im moving the mouse left right up down it dosent move 360c degrees at all ? I see the mouse cursor moving regular ? Its doing all the part ProcessInputCamera method but the mouse isnt movie my point of view 360c like in first person shooter. Just like in this demo: http://www.dhpoware.com/demos/xnaFirstPersonCamera.html

Comment: After looking at what the code does, that line is supposed to be there. The mouse is supposed to be reset to the center of the screen. I can't help you more than that.